# Use external libraries in Google App Engine(Python) with webapp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, webapp2

How can I use an external library like `requests` in GAE with webapp? There are various related questions on SOF but none that answer my question specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may to create dir in your project dir, let it will be `distlibs`. Than in `main.py` you should add this dir into `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path[0:0] = ['distlibs']
```

than you can `import` libs from `distlibs` dir (for example `wtforms`):

```
from wtforms import validators
...
```

#### Update:

In the case of the requests lib, once you extract ithub(github.com/kennethreitz/requests) will find it has a directory called requests in it. That is what you need to put somewhere in your code.

Comment: What do I need to keep inside distlibs folder? The complete library? For eg, should I just extract library downloaded in zip format from github(https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)?

Comment: I did as you said but the app engine returns an error while importing `requests`. If I uncomment it, the app works. I just want to confirm what you meant by placing any library into distlibs. Can you elaborate on this part?

Comment: I have simple app for `GAE` https://github.com/greggy/gae-blog maybe it helps you.

Comment: In the case of the requests lib, once you extract ithub(github.com/kennethreitz/requests) will find it has a directory called requests in it.  That is what you need to put somewhere in your code.

Comment: @greg : You can incorporate Tim's comment in your answer.